# how to make regex

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I was trying to solve a problem through regex. but It's very hard to make the regex. let look to an example maybe you people can help me out. and gave me some good source to learn regex. Now my problem is I want to make the regex for a sentence. e.g `www.facebook.com` `www.goole.com` `www.online.facebook.com` `www.live.com` if you see these example the `www` and `com` is same but the data between these are changing. i tried to make through this [link](https://regex101.com/) but can't.

Comment: You want to select  these sentence ?  try `^www.*com$`

Comment: Is it "www" and "com" or "www." and ".com"? Something like `(www\..*\.com)` - note that you have to escapa a literal . with a \

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: @DigvijayS bro and what about if i want to just find facebook in the middle and forget about starting and ending. as you suggest me ^www.*com$ and it worked.

Comment: @3limin4t0r my attempt was this ^*facebook*$ everything before facebook and everything after facebook

Comment: `^*facebook*$` this should be `^.*facebook.*$`.  `^` <-- Start of record `.` <-- any character. `*` <--  any number of repetition of the previous character  `$` <-- end of the record

Comment: `*` is often used as wildcard, but in regex it has a specific meaning. It says to repeat the character before zero or more times. `.` is any character. So `*` should be `.*` If you're interested in learning regex, there are a lot of useful links under the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good starting point.